# Rails update database after certain amount of time has gone by

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to update a column in my database if a book was created more than 25 seconds ago (when deploying, it will be 7 days ago, but I can't wait that long :)).

**Models:**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author, :date, :description, :order, :title, :user_id, :author, :status, :queued
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :user_id, :name, :bio
  has_many :books
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  @book = Book.new

  @books = Book.select("DISTINCT name, id") # Not used right now

  @sequence = @user.books

  @sequence.each do |book|
    book.created_at >= 25.seconds.ago ? book.queued = false : nil
  end
end
```

**User show view:**

```
<% @sequence.order("created_at DESC").where(:queued => false).each do |book| %>
```

Am I even close to getting this to work? What am I doing wrong? As you can see, I want to change the "queued" attribute to false after 25 seconds...

**Edit**

I've been told I need to use something like Heroku's Scheduler for this to work. Is there no way for this to update the database without something like that?

Comment: Not related to the question but: You should do `book.queued = false if book.created_at >= 25.seconds.ago` instead of `book.created_at >= 25.seconds.ago ? book.queued = false : nil`

Comment: Well that's a start. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a different approach. Instead of having a field to know if it' queued use a scope (a query for queued books)

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :queued, where('created_at <= ?', 25.seconds.ago)
  scope :not_queued, where('created_at > ?', 25.seconds.ago)
end
```

So now in your controller you can do something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @book = Book.new

    @not_queued_books = @user.books.not_queued
  end
end
```

Does it resolve your problem or you really need to have that column? Because with a scope it totally works and it's away more flexible and easy to implement!

---

If you want to see the ones not_queue by default `Book.all` and have a scope to see the queued ones here is an example

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :queued, where('created_at <= ?', 25.seconds.ago)
  scope :not_queued, unscoped.where('created_at > ?', 25.seconds.ago)
  scope :date_desc, order("created_at DESC")
  default_scope not_queued
end


class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @book = Book.new
  end
end
```

So now in your view just do this:

```
<% @user.books.date_desc.each do |book| %>
```

Notice now the default scope is books not queued and I moved the ordering also to a scope. Of course you can do this books.date_desc in your controller wich should preferable.

---

So as you said in the comment you have the issue of evaluation in scopes. Well, this is because the scope is "cached" when you start the app, so `25.seconds.ago` will be relative to the time you started the app instead of the 25 seconds ago from now as you want to. There are plenty resources explaining this, and you should go check them if you don't understand what I'm saying. For example in this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3

So what you have to do? You have to wrap your scopes with a lambda so it will be evaluated every time you use the scope instead of evaluating when you start the app.

Like this:

```
  scope :queued, lambda { where('created_at <= ?', 25.seconds.ago) }
  scope :not_queued, lambda { unscoped.where('created_at > ?', 25.seconds.ago) }
  scope :date_desc, order("created_at DESC")
  default_scope not_queued
```

Also instead of `lambda { ... }` you can use the new 1.9 shorthand `-> { ... }` instead

Comment: Yes, I was told to use a scope, but didn't quite understand how. This puts it very clearly, thanks! It doesn't seem to be working though. Whenever I add a book, it automatically goes to the list, not waiting 25 seconds. Do I need to modify the form or my loop in the view?

Comment: @TrevanHetzel Take a look now

Comment: Okay, I've found something odd. I'm using your original code (before you updated it). After 25 seconds has gone by, a book doesn't move. BUT if I simply save the model file (don't even have to make any changes, just a save), it updates and moves to the other list! Why would that be? Is it because the database just isn't getting updated?

Comment: oh! Ok, I know what's happening, and I'm glad that happened now because it mostly happens when running in production, maybe you are running in production now? :s Will update my answer

Comment: I'm still running in development, but am pushing to Heroku soon :)

Comment: I'm not sure why it happened but just check my update and see if it does the trick :)

Comment: Hey Ismael, I have an updated question for this. Would you be available to discuss this in chat? What I need to do now is: If the latest NONQUEUED book was created 25 seconds or more, change the status of the newly created queued book to nonqueued. My business logic was kind of off when you were helping me earlier.