# Updating enum record after specific timeframe has passed in relation to created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Goal:** To update a record in my Orders Model once a specific time frame has passed, if the record hasn't already been updated.

**I found this SO post:** [Rails update database after certain amount of time has gone by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093117/rails-update-database-after-certain-amount-of-time-has-gone-by)

I am struggling to understand how this would help my situation in updating the record.

The clarify, this is what is in my Order Model:

```
enum order_status: {created: 1, charged: 2, cancelled: 3 }
```

I am thinking of code like this, within my order model:

```
  def cancel_orders
    if Order.where(order_status: [1] && "created_at < (Date.now - 7)").update_all(order_status: [3]
  end
```

Although, I am not positive how I can apply this?

I then created this:

```
scope :cancel_orders, -> { (Order.where(order_status: [1] && "created_at < (Date.now - 7)").update_all(order_status: [3]) }
```

Although, none of the records updated.

What i want is when, after 7 days have passed, to change the `order_status` record to `3` or `cancelled` (yes it is spelled wrong) - but only is the record isn't already `2` or `3` OR only if it is currently at `1`.

I do see there is this gem: https://github.com/javan/whenever --- but i do want to avoid having this gem for no good reason.

Comment: Have you considered using cron with a rake task? I've used this solution lots of times. If interested I can elaborate it more.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I am beginning to realize that may be the only way.  For whatever reason i was hoping the app would be constantly checking itself, which kind of doesn't make sense - so it wouldn't know the time difference unless the database already knew.

Comment: Yep. As far as I know, the gems that do this job, internally are wrappers for cron or alike systems depending on the OS.

Comment: `Order.where(order_status: [1] && "created_at < (Date.now - 7)")` this query is not valid.

Comment: Did you check what are current `order_statuses` for your existing orders? If there is no any updated it might be that order_status flag is `nil`

Comment: Ended up creating a cron job with `Order.where(order_status: [1]).where('created_at <= ?', 25.seconds.ago).update_all(order_status: "canceled")` and working nicely --- 25 is just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a good solution, you could do it inside a callback if you wanna avoid cron job:

```
class Order
  before_create :cancel_orders

  private
    def cancel_orders
      self.class.where("order_status = 1 AND created_at < ?", DateTime.now - 7.days).update_all(order_status: 3)
    end
end
```

Comment: I ended up creating a cron job with basically that exact code (its listed above in the comments under the OP).  A cron job seems the only way to do it effectively so things are on a timely basis... i do like your way and is a creative way to avoid doing the cron job